# How to debug and fix Diverging implicits

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm a beginner to scala and I'm trying to wrap my head around diverging implicit expansions.

Here's my toy code:

```
class FooList[T](implicit ord: Ordering[T]) {

}

class Human(val score: Int) extends Ordering[Human] {


  override def compare(x: Human, y: Human): Int = {
    return x.score.compareTo(y.score);  
  }
}


object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val h = new Human(100)
    val lst = new FooList[Human]();
  }
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
diverging implicit expansion for type Ordering[Human]
starting with method comparatorToOrdering in trait LowPriorityOrderingImplicits


not enough arguments for constructor FooList: (implicit ord: Ordering[Human])FooList[Human].
Unspecified value parameter ord.
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/wkSrZ6BMQKW9ZJrsZhlITQ

I'd love a pointer or two in the right direction :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "diverging" message is a bit confusing here, the real problem is a misunderstanding about how type classes work. This is what it should look like:

```
class FooList[T](implicit ord: Ordering[T]) {
}

case class Human(score: Int)

implicit object HumanOrdering extends Ordering[Human] {
  def compare(x: Human, y: Human): Int =
    x.score.compareTo(y.score)
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val h = new Human(100)
    val lst = new FooList[Human]()
  }
}
```

Note that the `Human` class is just a simple data type. There is a separate `implicit object` that implements ordering for `Human` objects by extending `Ordering[Human]`.

The main point about a typeclass is that the behaviour is not part of the original class but is bound to it by creating an `implicit` value of the appropriate type. This allows you to add multiple behaviours to classes without having to modify the underlying class itself.

---

Note that you can put this `implicit object` inside the class object if you want to keep things a bit cleaner:

```
object Human {
  implicit object HumanOrdering extends Ordering[Human] {
    def compare(x: Human, y: Human): Int =
      x.score.compareTo(y.score)
  }
}
```

Comment: ah, thanks for the fix! I see how typeclasses are intended to be used. But I'm still confused why my code sample doesn't compile...why isn't it able to contextually infer the `Ordering` for a Human, seeing as Human extends `Ordering[Human]`?

Comment: There needs to be an `implicit` value of type `Ordering[Human]` and you don't define one of them. Technically you could make `h` an `implicit val` and it would all work, but it would be a bit weird!